# Non-standard evaluation + operator overloads within a function call

Tags: r

I've been fascinated lately by Hadley Wickhams [Non-standard Evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) examples in R, but I'm not sure what I want to do is possible.

I want to have a closure-based environment where you pass expressions that get evaluated (in NSE ways), similar to how subset works. The problem though, is that to do so I think I need to fundamentally change how arguments are passed.

For example,

```
g <- function(setup_stuff){
  function(x) {
    substitute(x)
  }
}
```

will give me the expression assigned to x if I so something like:

```
test <- g("Setup stuff")
test(1:10)
# 1:10
```

Similarly, I can do something like:

```
g <- function(setup_stuff){
  function(x) {
    sys.call(x)
  }
}
```

Which will usually give me kind of what I'm looking for--a completely unevaluated argument list:

```
test <- g("setup variables")
test(1:10)
# test(1:10)
```

But this all relies on the idea that I pass variables the "standard" way, by delimiting assigned parameters with commas. I *want* to have something like:

```
g <- function(setup_stuff){
      function(...) {
        # Capture named expression(s) before evaluation 
        substitute(...) 
      }
    }
```

Such that, for example, I can evaluate the arguments in a based on their named and the operators passed in, for example I've been trying to overload the logical operator &, but I just receive an error before the function to do NSE is even called:

```
test <- g("Setup stuff")
test(a=1 & b=2)
# > test(a=1 & b=2)
# Error: unexpected '=' in "test(a=1 & b="
```

I know I could *probably* do half-accomplish this by overloading the '&' and the '=' operator for some specific class, and just return the unevaluated call, but then a and b would need to be objects of that class, but I was wondering if I was missing something that someone can easily see?

Comment: I do not understand what `test(a=1 & b=2)` is supposed to return. You can do this: `test <- function(expr) eval(substitute(expr)); a <- 1; b <- 2; test(a==1 & b==2)` and you don't even need `substitute` there since you pass an expression.

Comment: I would like test to return `test(a=1 & b=2)`, also, I'm wondering if I can achieve that using `=`, instead of `==`

Comment: So, you want to return an expression that is not valid syntax? Why?

Comment: I want to do a NSE approach where I can determine the syntax/semantics, partially in the sense that I want to have an environment with it's own API. I fully realize I could use use the `==`, but I would like to change the semantics of `=` and `,`

Comment: and that's a bad idea, since you need to write your own parser for that. `=` and `,` are very low-level. They aren't even functions (like almost everything else) and you can't redefine them in R.